# how to push my project to github in a default branch, or merge two github branches remotely?

Tags: git, github

I created an `editor project` by `angular`, I want to push it in `githup`, I followed the following steps (I executed the following `git` commands):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "push editor project"
```

all this in `branch` local `master`.
I create a `github account`.
I create an "editorangular" repository in branch main.
I executed the commands:

```
git remote add origin master git@github.com:najib132/editorangular.git
git remote -v
```

(it gives me two links:

```
origin git@github.com:najib132/editorangular.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:najib132/editorangular.git (push)
```

)
when i executed command

```
git push -u origin main
```

it gives me error:

```
$ git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:najib132/editorangular.git'
```

then I execute command: `git push -u origin master`
it creates a `remote` branch `master`.
in github branch `main` it not from my project, and when i change `branch` to master i find my `project`.
so I want to `merge` between these two remote branchs `master` and `main`, or push my project directly to the default branch `main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Merge locally and push
- Pull request on the remote

**Option 1: Merge locally and Push**

on your command line while on the master branch, you can do the following commands:

```
git checkout main
```

if that fails saying the main branch doesn't exist or something, then fetch it from the remote

```
git fetch
```

and check it out

```
git checkout origin/main
```

This will put you on a detached branch, go ahead and attach it locally.

```
git checkout -b main
```

Now that you are on the `main` branch you can merge your `master` branch to your `main` branch

```
git merge master
```

This will merge the `master` branch into the `main` branch. You might end up with a merge conflict. That is a separate issue is out of the scope of this question in my opinion, but please feel free to search here on stack overflow for similar questions to solve that separate issue. Once you have satisfied the merge and the state of your local `main` branch is how you would like it, push it up to the remote.

```
git push -u origin main
```

At this point your code will be on the main branch both locally and on the remote, and also on the master branch. You might want to delete your master branch. You have to delete it on both the remote and locally.

To delete the branch on the remote, issue the following command:

```
git push origin :master
```

> Note the colon (:) before the branch name

To delete the branch locally, issue the following command while on some branch other than the one you are trying to delete

```
git branch -d master
```

you might get a warning about it not being synced to the remote, it suggests capitalizing the `-D` switch to force it. go ahead and do this if that is the case.

**Option 2: Create a pull request on the remote.**

Follow the instructions on this page - https://github.com/najib132/editorangular/compare/main...master

How to get there:
Select the "Pull Requests" menu option at the top and click the green "New Pull Request" button
[image]

Then select which branch you are merging from and into before clicking "Create pull request"
[image]
You will have the opportunity to add any additional details you would like here.
[image]
Scroll down to the bottom to finalize the merge
[image]

and complete it.
[image]

**Bonus Option: Make master your default branch**

Visit the settings for the repository and under the "Branches" menu you can select the default branch. That page can be directly accessed by you at this link - https://github.com/najib132/editorangular/settings/branches
[image]

> Note: You may still want to clean up your main branch by deleting it both on the remote and locally.

Comment: thx for u answer , I followed the steps of 1st method and when I execute the command `git push -u origin main` it gives me error:
`To github.com:najib132/editorangular.git
  ! [rejected] main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:najib132/editorangular.git'`

Comment: That means that your `main` branch has content on it that isn't in your `master` branch. They are divergent. Under usual circumstances this is a dangerous position to be in as the following instruction I am about to give could result in data loss. But in your case it appears that it's a new repo and the remote `main` holds nothing of value. If your certain there is nothing on the remote `main` branch you want to keep, issue the command `git push -u origin main --force`. This will overwrite the remote main with what you have locally.